# Swift: What instance of my class is in the view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, swift2

I'm building an app with a container view holding a tableView controller. I create this tableView, but I don't know how to access this object again so I can call function on it. Currently there is a BucketTableViewController object being created automatically (maybe from the storyboard). Then later I want to call a function on it and create another BucketTableViewController object. I can verify they are unique with print statement on that method. How do I set a variable for an object that is the original object?

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {


    var bigArray = ["M", "A", "R", "C"]
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        reachForWebsite()    
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func reachForWebsite(){
        let url = NSURL(...)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                ...
                // HERE IS THE ISSUE
                var bucketsVC = BucketTableViewController()
                bucketsVC.updateBuckets(self.bigArray)
            } catch let myJSONError {
                print(myJSONError)
            }
        }
        task!.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make `bucketsVC` an instance variable?

Comment: @ZoffDino Would you mind explaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab a reference to it from `prepareForSeque(_:sender:)` in the view controller that owns the container.  Make sure that identifier matches the name of the identifier you've set on the segue from the storyboard in Interface Builder.  Or you can omit the identifier part if you know for certain that there are no other segues with destination's of type `BucketTableViewController`.

```
class BucketTableViewController: UITableViewController {}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var bucketViewController: BucketTableViewController!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        super.prepareForSegue( segue, sender: sender )

        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? BucketTableViewController where segue.identifier == "embeddedBuketViewcontroller" {
            self.bucketViewController = vc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to make a segue because the table view is already up and running in the view. I don't need to go to it. I just need to the object that it belongs to

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a container view in Interface Builder, which connects a view controller through an "embed" segue.  This type of segue is different than others in that it isn't a transition, but is merely the mechanism for embedding that view controller in its container.  This will be called when view controller is loaded.

Comment: This is the correct answer (voted). When you use a container view to host a child view controller, the link it sets up is an embed segue. It's strange, but it is a special case of a segue, and the `prepareForSegue` method does fire. The embed segue is invoked as soon as the parent view controller's view is loaded.

Comment: @PatrickLynch  You were correct and it is now working. Thanks for the help I was never gonna figure this out. Also helpful the Duncan validated your claim. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

A comment is too tight for this, so I'm making it an answer. You can make bucketsVC` an instance variable:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var bucketsVS : BucketTableViewController?

    func reachForWebsite(){
        ...
        do {
            self.bucketsVC = BucketTableViewController()
            self.bucketsVC!.updateBuckets(self.bigArray)
        } catch {
            ...
        }

        // Now you can use it anywhere within your UIViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: When the project launches it creates a BucketTableViewController. `self.bucketsVC = BucketTableViewController()` creates another unique object. I want bucketsVC to be the original object created at launch (before code)